# What is the difference between Brother label printer models QL810W and QL810WC?

Tags: printer, brother-printer

I can’t find the Brother QL810W in stock anywhere and the QL810WC has appeared on the manufacturer’s [website](https://www.brother-usa.com/products/ql810wc). What is different about this new model?

Answer (score 1):

The features of the two printers are identical but the newer QL810WC appears to be packaged in a slightly smaller box that weighs less (5.5 lbs vs 5.8 lbs). The printer itself appears to have the same dimensions (5.0" x 9.2" x 5.7") and weight (2.4 lbs) according to the manufacturer’s website.

- [QL810W](https://www.brother-usa.com/products/ql810w) (older)
- [QL810WC](https://www.brother-usa.com/products/ql810wc) (newer)